# URL construction using okHttpClient

Tags: java, okhttp

I am getting a problem with constructing a URL with okHttpClient. I am getting 
below error in URL construction (http://16.234.156.25:88/example)

Please find the code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

            String host = "16.234.156.25";
            int port = 88;

            String port1 = Integer.toString(port);
            String ipadd = host + ":" + port1;

            URI uri = new URI(ipadd);
            String finalURL = uri.toString();

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

            map.put("", finalURL):

            for (Entry<String, String> m : map.entrySet()) {

                Request request = new Request.Builder()

                        .url("http://" + m.getValue() + "/example").get()
                        .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                        .addHeader("postman-token", "e6335509-3e1d-54c8-a975-dc9430e6d115").build();
```

Error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal
>   character in scheme name at index 0: 16.234.156.25:88 at
>   java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)

Comment: That is because your ipadd will become 16.234.156.25:88. Change ipadd as "String ipadd = "http://" + host + ":" + port1;"

Comment: I already added  "http:// " in requst url (.url("http://" + m.getValue() + "/example").get()), I want to add only host and port

Comment: that is 16.234.156.25:88

Comment: URI uri = new URI(ipadd); this does not accept host:port.

Comment: you have colon instead of semicolon here:  map.put("", finalURL)`:`

Comment: To prove, here is code which will give same error,

public static void main(String args[]) {
  try {
   URI uri = new URI("16.234.156.25:88");
  } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

 }

Comment: Then, how i will get this requirement using Okhttp

Comment: Try this,
URI uri = new URI("http://"+ipadd);
String finalURL = uri.toString();
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("", finalURL):

for (Entry<String, String> m : map.entrySet()) {
Request request = new Request.Builder()
.url(m.getValue() + "/example").get()
.addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
.addHeader("postman-token", "e6335509-3e1d-54c8-a975-dc9430e6d115").build();

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very good. The "scheme" is the first part of the URL, before the "://". The problem is that you didn't provide one. I'm guessing you need an "http" or "https". Look at the Javadoc for the URI class; you need more than just an IP address.

Good luck.

Comment: I already given the scheme name in request url (http://" + m.getValue() + "/example").get()). i want m.getValue() as 16.234.156.25:88

Comment: Look at the entire stacktrace. What line of your code is the source of the exception? What line does "http://" occur at in your code? If it is after the other line, it's too late. As I said, the problem is with the the construction of the URI instance.